# Oracle SQL grouping one column based on other column values

Tags: sql, oracle

My Table:

```
con_ref     col_ref   sal
  1           NON     25
  1           COL     36
  1           COL     12
  1           NON     13
  2           NON     25
  2           NON     6
  2           NON     33
  3           COL     42
  3           NON     51
  4           NON     63
  4           NON     31
  4           NON     15
```

I want to group above data on `Con_ref` column where `col_ref` value is just '`NON`'. so if the `col_ref` has both '`NON`' and '`COL`' this should exclude.

Desired Output:

```
CON_REF  sum(SAL)
2          64
4         109
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
with sample_data as (select 1 con_ref, 'NON' col_ref, 25 sal from dual union all
                     select 1 con_ref, 'COL' col_ref, 36 sal from dual union all
                     select 1 con_ref, 'COL' col_ref, 12 sal from dual union all
                     select 1 con_ref, 'NON' col_ref, 16 sal from dual union all
                     select 2 con_ref, 'NON' col_ref, 25 sal from dual union all
                     select 2 con_ref, 'NON' col_ref, 6 sal from dual union all
                     select 2 con_ref, 'NON' col_ref, 33 sal from dual union all
                     select 3 con_ref, 'COL' col_ref, 42 sal from dual union all
                     select 3 con_ref, 'NON' col_ref, 51 sal from dual union all
                     select 4 con_ref, 'NON' col_ref, 63 sal from dual union all
                     select 4 con_ref, 'NON' col_ref, 31 sal from dual union all
                     select 4 con_ref, 'NON' col_ref, 15 sal from dual)
-- end of mimicking a table called sample_data with data in it
select con_ref,
       sum(sal)
from   sample_data
group by con_ref
having count(case when col_ref != 'NON' then 1 end) = 0;

   CON_REF   SUM(SAL)
---------- ----------
         2         64
         4        109
```

---

ETA: The same result as requested without using `GROUP BY` (N.B. this is for Oracle; I have no idea whether it would work on other platforms):

```
with sample_data as (select 1 con_ref, 'NON' col_ref, 25 sal from dual union all
                     select 1 con_ref, 'COL' col_ref, 36 sal from dual union all
                     select 1 con_ref, 'COL' col_ref, 12 sal from dual union all
                     select 1 con_ref, 'NON' col_ref, 16 sal from dual union all
                     select 2 con_ref, 'NON' col_ref, 25 sal from dual union all
                     select 2 con_ref, 'NON' col_ref, 6 sal from dual union all
                     select 2 con_ref, 'NON' col_ref, 33 sal from dual union all
                     select 3 con_ref, 'COL' col_ref, 42 sal from dual union all
                     select 3 con_ref, 'NON' col_ref, 51 sal from dual union all
                     select 4 con_ref, 'NON' col_ref, 63 sal from dual union all
                     select 4 con_ref, 'NON' col_ref, 31 sal from dual union all
                     select 4 con_ref, 'NON' col_ref, 15 sal from dual)
-- end of mimicking a table called sample_data with data in it
select distinct con_ref,
                sum_sal
from   (select con_ref,
               sum(sal) over (partition by con_ref) sum_sal,
               count(case when col_ref != 'NON' then 1 end) over (partition by con_ref) cnt_non_non_con_ref
        from   sample_data)
where  cnt_non_non_con_ref = 0;

   CON_REF    SUM_SAL
---------- ----------
         4        109
         2         64
```

Comment: Perfect Thanks @Boneist

Comment: Is there a way of obtaining the same output without using group by. What I mean is just by using select statement. @boneist

Comment: Why don't you want to use group by? You're wanting to sum the sal columns, so you're going to have to use the SUM() function. Now it's  probably possible to achieve the same result using the analytic functions `SUM()` and `COUNT()` along with `DISTINCT` but why would you bother when you can do it all in a simple group by statement?

Comment: @BoneistBecause I have other code which is not allowing me to use this. sum(case  -- B63
            when tstype <> 'ONG'
              then WAPI
            else 0 
          end) as B63_drawn, So I need to uuse my existing vaue in the total sum.

Comment: What other code? If you've got something that can't cope with passing a simple group by statement across into a database (which is what I assume you're talking about here), then I doubt that it'll cope with something more complex! I have added an alternative to my answer, but I'd be very surprised if you could use that instead of the GROUP BY version.

Comment: Your other alternative is to create a view using the group by statement version, and then call the view from your code.

Comment: It looks very much like you've provided an over-simplified question. Sounds like you need to go back and re-edit it so that it represents your actual situation much more accurately. Where does `sum(case -- B63 when tstype <> 'ONG' then WAPI else 0 end) as B63_drawn` enter into the original example?

Comment: Thanks I will update my question or post new one with more clear example.

Comment: Hi @Boneist what is the opposite of the above query.  want to group above data on unique Con_ref column where col_ref value has both 'COL' and  'NON'. So the Con_ref records can be ignored where col_ref has multiple values.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean; do you mean that you want to display records that have both 'COL' and 'NON'? What if a con_ref has rows with three statuses (eg. 'COL', 'NON' and 'AHA') - what do you want displaying then? All rows? No rows? Only the COL + NON rows? Perhaps it would be better if you could update your question with sample input and output data that more accurately reflects what you're after?

Answer (score 0):

Your table and its data :

[image]

And this code block solve your problem, check it :

`select mt.con_ref
      ,sum(mt.sal)
  from mytable mt
 where mt.col_ref = 'NON'
   and not exists (select *
          from mytable mt1
         where mt1.con_ref = mt.con_ref
           and mt1.col_ref <> 'NON')
 group by mt.con_ref
         ,mt.col_ref`

And output this :

[image]